# How to find XAML Controls with FrameworkElement.FindName(String) Method?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

My **`MainWindows.xaml`** contains this.

```
<TextBox AutomationProperties.Name="LinkDrive TextBox" x:Name="MyName"/>
```

Then I'm wanting in the **`MainWindows.xaml.cs`** to modify the `TextBox.Text` property.

So I have to find the right element.
I don't know if this is the proper way. ‍♂️
[FrameworkElement.FindName(String) Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.frameworkelement.findname?view=winrt-19041)

```cs
public sealed partial class MainWindow :Window {
   public MainWindow() {
      this.InitializeComponent();
   }

   private void btn_click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) {
     // I think I have to go here with somethink like this?
     // this.Current.MainWindow.FindName("MyName");
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you define the `x:Name` in your XAML, then you can directly access the named element from inside the methods of your code-behind.

```
   private void btn_click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) {
     // Just call the named element directly here.
     MyName.Text = "Hello";
   }
```